# Create and throw exceptions based upon names

Tags: java

I have a list of exceptions (with package name path: `com.a.b.ExceptionA`) and error codes map.

Now, user will call `new ApiException(errorcode,"message")`, or   `new ApiException(errorcode,"message", Throwable t)`. Then, inside `BaseException`, I want to create ExceptionA,B based upon errorcode and throw it.

I can look up the map and get the exception type path, but how to create the exception and throw it? So some thing like below? or any better approach?

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.a.b.ExceptionA");
Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = cons.newInstance("message");
throw object;
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, here the objective iam inquiring is to create exception object dynamically based upon the error code type and then throw it based upon passed in arguments.

Comment: The approach looks correct.  But since you can't throw an Object, cast it to Throwable before throwing.

Comment: Not sure, why it is marked as duplicate?

Comment: With this approach, we create two objects(ApiException and IndividualException say ExceptionA), but i want to create one object and throw that based upon error code passed.